# jssor target slide in another page/document

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I want to target a specific slide with link. But the hyperlink and the slider are in different pages.
The idea is to make a separate navigation page.
Let's say the slider in slider.html and the page with the link is nav.html

```
<div id="slider1_container">
    <div u="slides">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="images/1.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="images/thumb-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="images/1.jpg" />
            <img u="thumb" src="images/thumb-1.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: EJS to the rescue ! http://www.embeddedjs.com/

Comment: I don't understand. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

This is called **templating**.

For example I want my navigation bar to always be at the top with the same items on every webpage. I would have a separate html file for the navigation bar and a footer and `require` that in my pages!

I mentioned EJS because I thought you were using node however there are much simpler ways to use this if you are not using node. (Actually you can still use EJS but I'm not sure how)
Many libraries like requirejs  do this.

Here's a list: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript_templates